# Re-open master from a previous commit

Tags: git

I have the following master branch structure:

```
WrongCommit1-->WrongCommit2-->WrongCommit3       master
              /
             /
GoodCommit---                                    master
```

I'd like to "re-start" the master branch from the `GoodCommit`, do some changes and forget the Head ending with `WrongCommit3`.

How is it possible to do in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume `GoodCommit` is for you a `SHA-1`

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <GoodCommit>
git push --force origin master
```

Optionally, you can remove the wrong commits from the history

```
git gc
```

more: [how to git reset to head](https://devconnected.com/how-to-git-reset-to-head/)

Comment: why ? please follow the [docs git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) where this flag is explained more in-depth

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the 'proper' way to do it, but it works for me:

1. Revert back to `GoodCommit` using `git revert <id>` or with some GUI application like GitHub Desktop.
2. Force push into master with `git push --force origin master`, or again with that application.

This sets your machine back to the GoodCommit, then forcibly overrides any chagnes and places it into the top of master.

Comment: @St.Antario apologies, should be `--force`, not `--hard`. I personally use desktop GUI applications and they refer to it as a hard push sometimes!